# Why does my IP address keep ending up in hosts.deny file?

Tags: linux, apache, ip

At my organisation we've set up a linux server which runs one of our sites. It's been working fine and I have been able to SSH through into it (using Terminal on OSX) no problem.

As of earlier when I tried to `ssh root@123.123.123.123` (not my real IP) I was rejected with: `ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`

Having a look at the `/etc/hosts.deny` file I can see: `sshd: 123.123.123.123` in the list.

This means the IP which I have been using for months no problem has suddenly appeared in the list. I removed it, and was able to SSH in fine, ONCE, then on my second try I was rejected and looking at the list again, I can see we have been added to the list once more!

I have added our IP to the hosts.allow file, but no luck - still no access.

**Why do IP's appear in the** `hosts.deny` **file? 
How can I stop our IP appearing there?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned, probably a `fail2ban` or similar (look for `denyhosts` too - another popular).

The usual fix is to append your IP address to /etc/hosts.allow

This works for denyhosts at least

Comment: the actual solution was to remove our IP from /etc/hosts.deny, and to add it to /var/lib/denyhosts/allowed-hosts (I had to create that last file)

Answer (score 2):

You may have a system like fail2ban installed which adds you to the hosts.deny file if you enter your password incorrectly a few times..

Comment: hmmm... sounds plausible - but why after removing ourselves from the list, then putting in the password once, correctly, would we be added back to the list?

Comment: Probably because someone making connections from that host is doing something (like entering an incorrect password multiple times) which the intrusion detection system doesn't like. Reading the logs in /var/log should clear it up.